# Can't download java JDK for Mac from my country

Tags: java, macos, jvm, java-8, download

I live in Afghanistan. I was trying to install the latest version of java from here: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

But I can't download it. I get an error message:

[image: Error Message]

I am trying to install this version:  ***Java SE Development Kit 8u91***.

Is there a workaround for this particular issue? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use a proxy to avoid country detection

Comment: @Dazak i looked up some online proxies, two to be precise but neither worked. Could you tell me a good one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use VPN to download Java :)

Comment: I believe I'll have to go with that option. I had it in mind but my internet connection is terrible for downloads of the size and VPN connection slows it even more. Imagine, just 1mbps!! But an hour of waiting will do. Thanks mate! :-)

Comment: Yes people living in Afghanistan, Iran, North Korea and some other countries have restricted access to US software.

Comment: @SomaiahKumbera That's kinda stupid, right. Although I download Xcode and other developer tools and I never had any problem from the apple website. But just to download the Java SE, it doesn't let me?! I haven't even downloaded an IDE for java and you won't even let me download the Java SE. Lol.

Answer (score 3):

You can also download from alternative source ;)
https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Comment: See that on the page are the links to both JRE and JDK. Choose the one you need!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can try Opera developer version browser that comes with its own VPN in US. You need to be in Private Browsing mode (basically incognito mode).

http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/2016/04/free-vpn-integrated-opera-for-windows-mac/

Comment: Thanks mate. I downloaded a free VPN software called Better net and had to make do with that. The problem with VPN is that it slows down the connection but an hour of waiting did it. Thank you for letting me know that opera's developer version has that feature.